# Android ImageView.setBackgroundResource() doesn't work

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to `setBackgroundResource` for an `ImageView`, but it doesn't work.

Xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_index"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/homegray"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
/>
```

Activity code:

```
imgIndex = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.img_index);
imgIndex.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.homewhite);
```

How can I control my `ImageView`?

Comment: Where are you using this, is it in a popup window??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
imgIndex = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_index);
imgIndex.setImageResource(R.drawable.homewhite);
```

or

```
imgIndex = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_index);
imgIndex.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.homewhite));
```